# ormlite columns with DB default and no specified value don't appear in INSERT statement

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Is there a setting I can use to get ormlite to ignore columns that have a DB defined default when doing an insert and I have not provided a value for that column?

Answer (score 0):

InsertOnly does the job

provide an API that takes an Expression Visitor for the rare cases you don't want to insert every field

db.InsertOnly(new Person { FirstName = "Amy" }, ev => ev.Insert(p => new { p.FirstName }));
INSERT INTO "Person" ("FirstName") VALUES ('Amy')